# python merge sort issue

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, clrs

Not sure where I am going wrong with my implementation of merge sort in python.

```
import sys

sequence = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def merge_sort(A, first, last):
    if first < last:
        middle = (first + last) / 2
        merge_sort(A, first, middle)
        merge_sort(A, middle+1, last)
        merge(A, first, middle, last)

def merge(A, first, middle, last):
    L = A[first:middle]
    R = A[middle:last]

    L.append(sys.maxint)
    R.append(sys.maxint)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in xrange(first, last):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1

merge_sort(sequence, 0, len(sequence))
print sequence
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what is breaking my current implementation of merge sort.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: tip : `first < last` ?

Comment: Current output for provided sequence is [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6].

Comment: I've literally attempted to implement the pseudocode outlined in the CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms) textbook. Not sure where I'm going wrong :(

Comment: When running your code, I notice it first tries to sort [6]. Then it sorts [4]. Fine thus far. But then, it tries to sort [6,5,4]. It seems it should sort [6,5] or [5,4] first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    merge_sort(A, first, middle)
    merge_sort(A, middle+1, last) # BEEP
```

You only sort the second part from middle + 1, when you should start at middle. In fact, you never reorder the element at middle.

Of course you cannot write either

```
    merge_sort(A, first, middle)
    merge_sort(A, middle, last) # BEEP, BEEP
```

because when last = first + 1, you get middle == first and dive in an endless recursion (stopped by a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`)

So the way to go is:

```
    merge_sort(A, first, middle)
    if middle > first: merge_sort(A, middle, last)
```

After that little change, your implementation gives correct results.

Comment: Thanks, this is a clear answer and I'm glad I can now recognize that the middle index was the main cause. Both your answer and Anmol helped.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 errors in the code:

- `if first < last:` should be `if first < last and last-first >= 2:`
- `merge_sort(A, middle+1, last)` should be `merge_sort(A, middle, last)`

Comment: Isn't the first point merely an optimization? As long as the `middle` calculation rounds down, the code isn't incorrect.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, but I am still struggling to see how this additional check and modification of the middle index has fixed the original implementation :( Apologies if this seems dumb, but I would have expected the textbook to include additional details if this is the case.

Comment: Earlier, the middle element wasn't being included in any of the two halves. So, changing `middle+1` to `middle` includes it in the right half.

Comment: `if first < last - 1:` is a bit shorter and IMHO clearer.

Comment: @nuce Feel free to ask any more questions if you are still not clear. If you are satisfied, then you can close the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Thanks, middle element caught me off guard. I need to be careful with indexes.